# MySQL: creating a new user/trying to access the database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

My problem is: 
I had created a new user:`GRANT ALL PRIVILAGES ON sampdb.* TO 'monty'@'' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'`
This user had appiared in two databases: mysql.user(with no privilages at all) and mysql.db(with nearly all privilages except GRANT one). OK. 
After that I tried to access the sampdb database by this new user:`mysql -u monty -ppass sampdb`. MySQL answered: "Access denied for user 'monty'@'localhost (using password: YES)'.

Please, tell me, where did I mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to grant the privileges to `'monty'@'localhost'`, rather than `'monty'@''`. At the moment, you're trying to connect via localhost, and `'monty'@'localhost'` doesn't exist.

edit: Or `'monty'@'%'`, to allow connections from any host.

Comment: +1, or `'monty'@'%'` for all hosts, or a specific other host, as the need may be.

Comment: You must have a user with all privileges already in order to be running the GRANT command you quoted, so log in as that user and issue `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'monty'@''` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'monty'@'localhost'` and see what is output.